# docker pushing the same layer multiple times

Tags: docker, push

I built a docker image and am pushing it to docker hub. In the new build I only added two files, accounting for about 370 MB. While pushing, I can see the following output:

```
c240673ff7a6: Pushing [==============>                                    ]  542.8MB/1.902GB
e6ef6e88802b: Layer already exists
822f4f1fcbb4: Layer already exists
798af7b1a81e: Pushing [================>                                  ]  408.3MB/1.252GB
982c0856bcb4: Layer already exists
1fef33fc148c: Pushed
798af7b1a81e: Pushing [==================================>                ]  866.9MB/1.252GB
eb07dfebe492: Layer already exists
92e9ec704887: Pushed
798af7b1a81e: Pushing [================>                                  ]  407.2MB/1.252GB
```

Lines 4, 7 and 10 seem to have the same hash which I assume ist the ID of a layer. Why is that? The progress bar seems to show that there are three different uploads happening of with that ID.

I was expecting for each layer to be only pushed once. Also, in the Docker Desktop UI, the image is said to have a size of 5.1 GB, while just these pending uploads have a combined size of more than 5.65 GB.

I have read the [docker pull documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) but am none the wiser. Also, using a search engine and searching stackoverflow have not helped me find an answer to my question why docker seems to be pushing the same layer thrice.

Comment: Turns out it was just uploading one thing and for some reason displayed it multiple times:

```
c240673ff7a6: Pushed
e6ef6e88802b: Layer already exists
822f4f1fcbb4: Layer already exists
798af7b1a81e: Pushing [================>                                  ]  408.3MB/1.252GB
982c0856bcb4: Layer already exists
1fef33fc148c: Pushed
798af7b1a81e: Pushed
eb07dfebe492: Layer already exists
92e9ec704887: Pushed
798af7b1a81e: Pushing [================>                                  ]  407.2MB/1.252GB
52ad947270f1: Layer already exists
```

Comment: As you can see, the progress bar never changed for the two 'duplicate' uploads. To excuse myself I only upload at max. 128kBs so i'd have to stare very long to notice that there is only one progress bar moving.